# How to show the perticular part of a remote url web page in the pop up

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, popup

i have a pop up of size of 300x30 and i want to show the login boxes of facebook login page only not the whole page. that how can i do this. i want also that the whole header part should be included in pop up also. please reply.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be possible to embed Facebook in an iframe for security reasons - if you're using the API and the current user isn't logged into Facebook there's a small login popup which Facebook will render for you

Comment: but can we scrap the login part of the another website. i want only login part of the remote url page in the popup. i dont want to show the whole page from top left side in the popup.